# Cloning a struct's function field which contains reference to old struct

Tags: go, struct, clone

I have a struct which contains function field, and that field contains a reference back to the struct itself. I want to implement a Clone method on this struct which does a deep-copy, but the function field keeps the reference to the old struct always, hence I am unable to do a proper deep-copy.

Here is a very simplified version of my problem:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    name  string
    printName func()
}

func NewMyStruct() *MyStruct {
    return &MyStruct{}
}

func (s *MyStruct) SetName(n string) {
    s.name = n
}

func (s *MyStruct) SetPrint(fn func()) {
    s.printName = fn
}

func (s *MyStruct) Clone() *MyStruct {
    newS := &MyStruct{
        name:  s.name,
        printName: s.printName,
    }
    return newS
}

func main() {
    s := NewMyStruct()
    s.SetPrint(func() {
        fmt.Println(s.name)
    })

    s.printName() // prints "" as expected

    s.SetName("brother")
    s.printName() // prints "brother" as expected

    sClone := s.Clone()
    sClone.printName() // prints "brother" as expected

    sClone.SetName("sister")
    sClone.printName() // prints "brother" which I don't want it to
}
```

The main problem is that the print function is set on runtime, and it can be set to anything by the user, so there is no way for me to rewrite the closure in the Clone method. Is there a way to implement a proper deep-clone on this struct?

A solution I thought of is to make the function take the MyStruct as it's parameter so it's localized always, but that will break the interface, hence I am looking for any other solution.

**UPDATED:** Updated the code to show the constraints more clearly.

Comment: You set the `printName` to point to a closure. There is no way to copy that. You have to create a new closure with the new struct instance.

Comment: @CeriseLimón that works, but as I stated in the question I am looking for any other solution than that.

Comment: "I am looking for any other solution than that." You can stop looking, there is none.

Answer (score 0):

This is a closure problem，i think u can try doing this

```
func (s *MyStruct) PrintName() {
    fmt.Println(s.name)
}
```

Comment: Just updated the question now, please check it out. The problem is that the `printName` function set at the runtime, hence I can't possibly know the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `MyStruct.printName` at the very first lines which simply prints the `s.name`. It means this set function will print the initiated MyStruct `s`'s field `name`.

And your issue happens because when you call `MyStruct.Clone`, `MyStruct.printName` is using the same `s.printName` which points to the function you set by calling `s.SetPrint`.

You have 2 approaches to fix this:

- Accept an new function as parameter in `MyStruct.Clone` to override the `printName` so it can works correctly.
- Manually call `MyStruct.SetPrint` to update the function used.